# SQL: Is there a way of blocking two identical rows existing in one table

Tags: sql, sqlite

So while creating a table, i would like to add a condition making sure that two rows are not identical fully, not taking the ID into count. So one or more columns could be same, but not the full row. Is this possible? Ideally, I would like the method (if there is one) working in SQLite.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the columns (except the primary key) of your table were defined as `NOT NULL` then a `UNIQUE` constraint over all the columns:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    col1    TEXT NOT NULL,
    col2    TEXT NOT NULL,
    col3    TEXT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE(col1, col2, col3)
);
```

would be enough to guarantee that all the rows are unique.

But for a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    col1    TEXT,
    col2    TEXT,
    col3    TEXT
);
```

the unique constraint would not catch 2 rows like:

```
id  col1  col2  col3
--------------------
1   a     b     null
2   a     b     null
```

because `null`s are not considered equal.

What you need is 2 triggers, one `BEFORE INSERT` and the other `BEFORE UPDATE`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER unique_row_tablename_insert BEFORE INSERT ON tablename
BEGIN
  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM tablename t
      WHERE t.col1 IS NEW.col1 AND t.col2 IS NEW.col2 AND t.col3 IS NEW.col3 
    ) THEN RAISE (ABORT, 'The row already exists')
    END;    
END;

CREATE TRIGGER unique_row_tablename_update BEFORE UPDATE ON tablename
BEGIN
  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM tablename t
      WHERE t.id <> NEW.id AND t.col1 IS NEW.col1 AND t.col2 IS NEW.col2 AND t.col3 IS NEW.col3
    ) THEN RAISE (ABORT, 'The row already exists')
    END;    
END;
```

By using the operator `IS` instead of `=` you can match `null`s as equal.
These triggers will raise an error with the message: `'The row already exists'` and abort the operation in case the new/updated row matches an already existing row.

Answer (score 0):

Add a unique index to your table on all columns:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx ON yourTable (col1, col2, ..., colN); -- assuming N columns
```

With this index in place, any attempt to insert a record all of whose values match a record already in the table would fail with an error.

Comment: Though a `UNIQUE INDEX` will certainly do the job, usually you define a unique *constraint*, such as `CONSTRAINT <name> UNIQUE (col1, col2, col3, ...)` as part of the table definition.

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . I wouldn't say that one method is used more often than the other.  They are implemented the same way.  The constraint has the advantage that you can give the constraint a name.  (But then again, the index has the advantage that you can give the index a name.)

Comment: Neither the constraint nor the index will work in case there are columns with `null`s, because `null`s are not considered equal to each other.

Comment: Note SQLite  considers rows `(null, null)` and `(null, null)` to be different .